# How to get more than 100 units using Instagram Private Api?

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram-api

I find very cool library called Instagram Private Api and Im trying get all people subscribed on my Instagram for educational purposes.
But I can't get more than 100 units :(
Can somebody help me understand how to fix it?

````
from random import randint
from time import sleep



user_id = api.username_info('target')['user']['pk']

# Create a list of followers' usernames
usernames = []



next_max_id = followers.get('next_max_id')

while next_max_id:
    delay = randint(20,40)
    print("Sleep " + str(delay) + "s")
    sleep(delay)
    # Get a list of the user's followers
    followers = api.user_followers(user_id, rank_token=api.generate_uuid(),)
    next_max_id = followers.get('next_max_id')

    for follower in followers['users']:
        usernames.append(follower['username'])
    


# Print the list of followers' usernames
print(len(usernames))```
````

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://instagram-private-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#instagram_private_api.Client.user_followers), `user_followers` accepts a `max_id` keyword argument you can use to paginate the results. Why not try that and see what happens?

Comment: Since im newbie I still not understand how to implement what im reading in documentation

Can I ask you to give me a tip on this?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://instagram-private-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#instagram_private_api.Client.user_followers): you can pass `max_id` to offset the selection of users.

You can also look at the provided [example](https://github.com/ping/instagram_private_api/blob/master/examples/pagination.py).

Comment: Am I right that I need put 
```
followers = api.user_followers(user_id, rank_token=api.generate_uuid(), max_id = 100)
```
?
Unfortunately when I do this it give me nothing :(

Comment: tbh it's a weird api. look at the example, you have to call next_max_id = results.get('next_max_id')

Comment: Thank you @Facorazza! I just edit my code in question. Can I ask you to look on it?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
from instagram_private_api import Client, ClientCompatPatch

username = 'username'
password = 'password'

def get_all_followers(api, user_id, rank_token):
    followers = []
    next_max_id = True

    while next_max_id:

        if next_max_id == True:
            result = api.user_followers(user_id, rank_token)
        else:
            result = api.user_followers(user_id, rank_token, max_id=next_max_id)

        next_max_id = result.get('next_max_id')
        followers.extend([user['username'] for user in result['users']])

    return followers


if __name__ == '__main__':
    api = Client(username, password)
    user_info = api.username_info(username)
    user_id = user_info['user']['pk']
    rank_token = Client.generate_uuid()
    followers = get_all_followers(api, user_id, rank_token)
```

Comment: Such interesting way to do that